# Apache Ignite : Client and Server Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, ignite, gridgain

I have a server node based on the example mentioned in https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/ServerNode/Program.cs

Also in another process, I have a client with "ClientMode = true" like below.

```
        return new IgniteConfiguration(GetServerNodeConfiguration())
        {
            ClientMode = true
        };
```

The cache will hold the information of the "Employee" class, and I'm using IBinarySerializer to serialize the "Employee" and "Address" classes, and serializers are added into the IgniteConfiguration as below...

```
IgniteConfiguration.BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
                {
                    TypeConfigurations = new List<BinaryTypeConfiguration>
                    {
                        new(typeof(Employee)){Serializer = new EmployeeSerializer()},
                        new(typeof(Address)){Serializer = new AddressSerializer()},
                    }
                }
```

My questions are...

1. Do we need to have the "Employee" and "Address" classes both on the server and the client code? or do I just mention them on the client side?
2. Do we need to have the IBinarySerializer serializers in ignite BinaryConfiguration both on the server and the client code? or do I just mention them on the client-side?

Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

IBinarySerializer implementations

```
public sealed class EmployeeSerializer : IBinarySerializer
{
    public void WriteBinary(object obj, IBinaryWriter writer)
    {
        var employee = (Employee)obj;

        writer.WriteGuid("employeeId", employee.EmployeeId );
        writer.WriteString("name", employee.Name);
        writer.WriteObject("address", employee.Address);
    }

    public void ReadBinary(object obj, IBinaryReader reader)
    {
        var employee = (employee)obj;

        employee.EmployeeId  = reader.ReadObject<Guid>("employeeId");
        employee.Name = reader.ReadString("name");
        employee.Address = reader.ReadObject<Address>("address");
    }
}


public sealed class AddressSerializer : IBinarySerializer
{
    public void WriteBinary(object obj, IBinaryWriter writer)
    {
        var address = (Address)obj;

        writer.WriteString("street", address.Street);
        writer.WriteString("zip", address.Zip);
    }

    public void ReadBinary(object obj, IBinaryReader reader)
    {
        var address = (Address)obj;

        address.Street = reader.ReadString("street");
        address.Zip = reader.ReadString("zip");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, you need this information on each node.
Both sides have to know how to deserialize and serialize a record properly.

Though it's possible to work directly in binary mode using `BinaryObjectBuilder` without explicit models definition. It's not mandatory to define a custom `IBinarySerializer` either, the internal serializer will do the trick well enough unless you have some big models with dozens of fields defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, because my models are a bit complex including nested objects and arrays, so we have to define in both places right?

Comment: I'd say yes. Though it might depend on a use-case. Consider this: once you'd like to store your model in a cache, the data needs to be transformed into some binary format first, submitted to the appropriate server node (defined by a cache's key), and then placed in a data page inside B+ tree underneath. Once you read a record, it needs to be located inside a node's page memory first and then transferred to a caller for deserialization. If it's a client, there is no need for multiple serializations and a server should just resend this data as is.